# Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(inout inout $T6, inout inout$T11)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to randomise an object array using `NSArray` for a quiz app. Each Question number contains each array. I tried adding a sort into the `ViewDidLoad` and I get the following error.

> "Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(inout inout
>   $T6, inout inout$T11)"

I am using `Swift` with `xCode 6`. I am a beginner at iPhone App Development.

Code Below:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
{

    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
    {
        var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that array is immutable. You would need to do something like this:

```
func shuffleArray<T>(array:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    var swapArray = array

    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index-- {
        var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))

        swap(&swapArray[index], &swapArray[j])
    }

    return swapArray
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To obtain a variable copy of your input parameters in swift it suffices to declare these parameters as variable (notice the `var array`):

```
func shuffleArray<T>(var array: Array<T>) -> Array<T> { 
    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
    {
        var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }
    return array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple make your array as `inout`

```
func shuffleArray<T>(inout array: Array<T>) -> Array<T>
{

    for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
    {
        let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))
        swap(&array[index], &array[j])
    }
    return array
}
```

and when you call your function, you need to put `&` before the array variable like this:

```
var somet = [[1,2,3]]
shuffleArray(&somet)
```

Sidenote: I changed `j` from `var` to `let` cos you are not changing it